# how to make String Case Insensitive in Java Script String Case Insensitive Function

Tags: javascript, html

I am searching the data entered by user from array it is working fine but it is case sensitive i want to remove this casesensitive

```
    else if(document.getElementById('drop_down_list_1').value=="Beef"){
    if(document.getElementById('search_input').value==""){
    alert("Please Enter a charactor / word..");
     return false;
    }
    else{
    var con = document.getElementById('first_div');
    var con2 = document.getElementById('first_div2');
    var char = document.getElementById('search_input').value;
    var str = '';
    var j = 0;
    var ad = ['CLARIFIDE Deadlines 2012 - 2013 Nov','C','REPRODUCTIVE VACCINES — REPRODUCTIVE CLAIMS','M','M', 'R'];
   var len = ad.length;
   //var break_line = '<br>';
   for (j=0; j<len; j++) {
   var str = ad[j];
   var n=str.indexOf(char);
    if (n == 0)
    con.innerHTML += '<table id="results" width="920" border="1" style="margin:-30px 0 0 -10px;">      <tr><td>'
          + str
           + '</td><td colspan="4" align="right"><a href="presenter.command(\'viewPdf\',  {\'path\':%20\'/images/pdf/Beef/'+j+'.pdf\'});"><img src="images/view.png" style="margin-left:250px;">   </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/email.png"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr></table>'
        //+ break_line;
        //break_line = '<br>';
   }
  }
  }
```

so how to make the search case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing strings, an option for making it "case insensitive" is to call `.toUpperCase()` on both strings:

```
if (var1.toUpperCase() === var2.toUpperCase()) {
    // They match!
}
```

Comment: in this way if we enter e like this E then it will show result for both

Comment: Either make the string you are searching all upper or all lower case and search using all upper or all lower case respectively. Or search for both: `if (str.indexOf(char.toUpperCase()) != -1 || s.indexOf(char.toLowerCase() != -1)` or use a case insensitive regular expression.